# How to use Angular ngFor to create Bootstrap navbar links

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

[image]

The `Nav Link 1`,`Nav Link 2` and `Nav Link 3` buttons are defined in `app.component.html` with:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="onNavClick()" >Nav Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="onNavClick()" >Nav Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="onNavClick()" >Nav Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another three nav links `Nav Link 4`, `Nav Link 5` and `Nav Link 6` are created with

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let name of names">
    <a class="nav-link" >{{name}}</a>
</li>
```

Apparently, the ones that were created with `*ngFor` directive are rendered differently and loose any styling. How to fix this issue> Here is the link to Stackblitz project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sff2wk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are placing `li` tag after `ul` tag..

So you need to include,

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let name of names">
    <a class="nav-link" >{{name}}</a>
</li>
```

inside `ul` tag like,

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="onNavClick()" >Nav Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="onNavClick()" >Nav Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="onNavClick()" >Nav Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let name of names">
    <a class="nav-link" >{{name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> [**Forked Stackblitz here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jx8qnu)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
....
  <ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" >{{name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ng-container` does not fix the issue. Please illustrate if you believe otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: You should add that extract I presented inside of <ul></ul>, I am editing my answer.